# How to filter rows in sql based on an interval

Tags: sql

I have a database in SQL that I want to query. The data looks like this:

```
Date         ID    Value
20190304    100000  55
20180517    100000  67
20150630    100000  56
20130405    200000  89
20130506    200000  90
20140627    300000  76
20150705    300000  53
20140806    300000  68
20190530    300000  78
20150614    400000  99
```

Now I want to select all cases for every ID, but excluding the cases where the Date for a given ID is within one year of one of the other dates for a given ID. If the Date for a given ID is within one year of another date with the same ID, I only want to select the earliest date, and so on.

The end result would look like this:

```
Date         ID    Value
20180517    100000  67
20150630    100000  56
20130405    200000  89
20140627    300000  76
20150705    300000  53
20190530    300000  78
20150614    400000  99
```

I cannot find a simple way to do this within SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if dates are chained such as 2017-01-01, 2017-07-01, 2018-01-01, 2018-01-07?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strict interpretation of what you are asking for would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.date > t.date and
                        t2.date < t.date + interval '1 year'
                 );
```

Note that date operations are notoriously database-specific.  Your database may not support the standard syntax for adding a 1 year interval.  However, it no doubt has syntax to do this.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer Gordon. This worked for me, with a small adjustment. The date field is formatted as an integer, so just adding 10000 does the trick.